# Getting null value of a String when passing the variable from jsp to servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have a application in java 1.6 and I want to upgrade it to java 1.8, but the problem is , while transferring some variable from jsp to servlet giving **null**. its working fine with java 1.6.

jsp code:

```
Random rdm=new Random();
int rl=rdm.nextInt();

String hash1 = Integer.toHexString(rl);

String capstr=hash1.substring(0,4);

session.setAttribute("key",capstr);
```

and this is my servlet code :

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;


public class StrutsUploadAndSaveAction extends org.apache.struts.action.Action {

     private final static String SUCCESS = "success";
 private final static String FAILURE = "failure";
    @Override
  public ActionForward execute(

  ActionMapping mapping,

  ActionForm form,

  HttpServletRequest request,

  HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{

  StrutsUploadAndSaveForm myForm = (StrutsUploadAndSaveForm)form;

String Name = myForm.getUid();
String Password = myForm.getHash();

HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

session.setAttribute("Name",myForm.getUid());
session.setAttribute("Password",myForm.getHash());

String key=(String)session.getAttribute("key");
System.out.println("login page Action captcha Keys"+key);
String user = request.getParameter("number");
System.out.println(" login page Action captcha User"+user);
if(key.compareTo(user)==0)
{
return mapping.findForward("success");
}
else{
return mapping.findForward("failure");
}}}
```

and the error is:

type Exception report

message java.lang.NullPointerException

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processException(RequestProcessor.java:520)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:427)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)

root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    roseindia.net.StrutsUploadAndSaveAction.execute(StrutsUploadAndSaveAction.java:68)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:425)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

Comment: Which line is `roseindia.net.StrutsUploadAndSaveAction.execute(StrutsUploadAndSaveAction.java:68)` - i.e. where the NPE is thrown? Is it the `if(key.compareTo(user)==0)` line?

Comment: Yes , the line is  `if(key.compareTo(user)==0)`. 
Its because `key` holding null value.